# Formatting a shape in Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I want to format a shape via excel vba, but I always get the 424 object error. I want to put a text into the shape and change its color.

```
Sub 1()
    Dim clLeft As Double
    Dim clTop As Double
    Dim clWidth As Double
    Dim clHeight As Double
    Dim Datum As String
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Datum = InputBox("Welches Jahr")
    
    If Datum = 2023 Then
        
        Set cl = Range("F7")
        
        clLeft = cl.Left
        clTop = cl.Top
        clHeight = cl.Height
        clWidth = cl.Width
        
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, clLeft, clTop, Range("K36").Value * 80, 37).Select
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Test"
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(225, 140, 71)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
        
    ElseIf Datum = 2024 Then
        
        Set cl = Range("R7")
        
        clLeft = cl.Left
        clTop = cl.Top
        clHeight = cl.Height
        clWidth = cl.Width
        
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, clLeft, clTop, Range("K36").Value * 80, 37).Select
        
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Test"
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(225, 140, 71)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
        
    End Sub
```

Why do I get this error? I saw plenty of examples who did it the same way and didn't get one.

Comment: I get "Block If without End If" - post your actual code

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing...

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, clLeft, clTop, Range("K36").Value * 80, 37).Select
shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Test (IBS, KIT, CIT, UAT)"
shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(225, 140, 71)
```

with

```
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, clLeft, clTop, Range("K36").Value * 80, 37)

With shp
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Test (IBS, KIT, CIT, UAT)"
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(225, 140, 71)
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
End With
```

The same thing with your other one.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
Dim shp As Shape
```

and you have

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, clLeft, clTop, Range("K36").Value * 80, 37).Select
```

But nowhere do you actually assign a value to `shp`. I presume you meant to use

```
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, clLeft, clTop, Range("K36").Value * 80, 37)
```